# Accessing arcgis.com webmap layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

**Background:**

Our local newspaper contained this link to some upcoming forest management activity in the area:

https://usfs.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=021ff3371f584a54beb15cd481a8fbb5

Here's a screenshot of the resulting argis.com webmap:

[image]

**Problem:**

I would like access the prescribed fire polygon layer displayed in this webmap, either as a service or via download.  However, I'm unable to accomplish this seemingly simple task.  Here's what I've unsuccessfully tried:

1. Look for some sort of link (service url or layer download) in the webmap itself
2. Search for the polygon layer via my personal arcgis.com account.  Here my steps were to create a new map and search using *Add > Search for Layers, Add > Browse Living Atlas Layers,* and *Add > Add Layer From Web*.
3. From ArcMap (10.8.1), *Add > Add Data from ArcGIS Online* and search

**Question:**

How do I access the polygon layer in this webmap?

Comment: you can inspect the network traffic, and when you get a layer URL you can browse up to all other layers: https://services1.arcgis.com/gGHDlz6USftL5Pau/ArcGIS/rest/services  (whether you are permitted or not to use these layers is another question though...)

Comment: @JGH I can view the layers in the link you provided.  However, I could not find the layer from my OP.  Also, how does one "...inspect network traffic..."?

Comment: check the layers starting with "OKW", maybe. Look at the developer tools of your favorite browser, they typically have a `network` tab (right click in a webpage, inspect/dev tools, network)

Answer (score 0):

To get the data in **GeoJSON** use the long url

```
https://services1.arcgis.com/gGHDlz6USftL5Pau/ArcGIS/rest/services/OKW_2017RXFireUnitPolys_VIEW/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnCentroid=false&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token=
```

This can be done from the **query wizard** here
https://services1.arcgis.com/gGHDlz6USftL5Pau/ArcGIS/rest/services/OKW_2017RXFireUnitPolys_VIEW/FeatureServer/0/query

[image]

(in QGIS this will load with drag and drop) **but your looking for ArcGIS**. When in the Office next year can validate. screenshot shows the data in geojson/styled as the map legend.
[image]